# RethinkDB Query to Find Duplicate Email Addresses (records)

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

I have the following ReQL Query which Identifies distinct addresses, but can't seem to add the not() method to get the opposite.

```
r.db('mydb').table('users').orderBy(r.desc('email')).without('id').distinct()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not` operates on booleans. `.distinct().not()` doesn't modify the `distinct` operation. It just gets applied applies to its result, which doesn't make much sense.

You could instead do something like this

```
r.db('mydb').table('users')
 .group('email').count().ungroup()
 .filter(row => row('reduction').gt(1))('group')
```